# Can not Download video from youtube

Tags: android, youtube, download

I am using  http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=*VIDEO_ID* and from the data I get I am parsing the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map and I get the urls like

```
http://blah.youtube.com/videoplayback?blah
```

Earlier I could download the videos using this url but now I am not able to download the videos anymore. Anyone has a clue why?

Comment: It might work in some cases -> [GO HERE][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/429767/74504

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code to return the video urls:

all credits to youtube-dl I only copied the part of their script which you need for extracting the urls

```
video_id = "yourvideoid"
for el_type in ['&el=embedded', '&el=detailpage', '&el=vevo', '']:
    video_info_url = ('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=%s%s&   ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en'
                     % (video_id, el_type))
    request = urllib2.Request(video_info_url)
    try:
        video_info_webpage = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
        video_info = parse_qs(video_info_webpage)
        if 'token' in video_info:
            break
    except (urllib2.URLError, httplib.HTTPException, socket.error), err:
        print('ERROR: unable to download video info webpage: %s' % str(err))
video_url_list = video_info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'][0]
url_data_strs = video_info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'][0].split(',')
url_data = [parse_qs(uds) for uds in url_data_strs]
url_data = filter(lambda ud: 'itag' in ud and 'url' in ud, url_data)
url_map = dict((ud['itag'][0], ud['url'][0] + '&signature=' + ud['sig'][0]) for ud in  url_data)
print(str(url_map))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method isn't more enough: you should decrypt also the signature in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

No clue as to why, but it seems to be [affecting all downloader extensions](http://malaysia.answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=Ans_6xNo6cejU7csGqs0c0m4QAx.;_ylv=3?qid=20120913130136AA8hpdL), so it's almost certainly on YouTube's side.  I'm assuming it has something to do with intellectual property.  YouTube is "intended" to be a streaming site, not a video file repository.

[Shutaro at addons.mozilla.com](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/reviews/382210/) has discovered a workaround that entails forcing YouTube to revert to delivering the older .webm format.

Comment: Youtube-dl still works so it should be possible. If you bump into anything kindly share it here

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and from what I understand from someone else who has fixed it that we need to add a signature to the video link (the mp4 or 3gp links that are returned)... I'm looking into this and will update. I hope you can do the same if you discover anything.

Comment: Sure I will update if I can get something to work. Kindly update if you find a fix. Youtube-dl still works and I am currently trying to check out how thy r doing it.